# Uniqueness of solution to nonlinear first-order initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I recently came across an interesting exercise (not homework) about the existence and uniqueness of solutions $y \in \mathcal{C}^1((0, \infty))$ to a given initial value problem. I was given the following:
$$\log(y') + \log(y) - \log(x) = -xy' + y, \qquad y(1) = 1,$$
and was asked to prove that there is only one solution. By inspection, the candidate solution must be $y(x) = x$ and so only uniqueness remained. This is where I am stuck, because it seems that this ODE cannot be explicitly solved. No amount of manipulations I have tried, such as rearranging or taking exponentials to simplify, seemed to yield any progress, and it seems that the usual existence and uniqueness theorem cannot be applied because the ODE is not of the form $y' = f(x, y)$. I have also tried assuming that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions to the initial value problem to try and show that it must be the case that $y_1 = y_2$, to no avail. I also hesitate to differentiate the ODE with respect to $x$ for more information, because solutions were only assumed to be $\mathcal{C}^1$.

So after thinking about this for a couple of days now, I feel as though there must be some trick or argument that does not involve solving the ODE that I am not seeing to deduce that $y(x) = x$ is indeed the unique solution. But now I am out of ideas, so any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: You do not need the explicit form, only that $\ln(y')+xy'=f(x,y)$ can be locally uniquely be solved for $y'$. This excludes the curve $xy'+1=0$.

Comment: Do you need to ensure unique solutions on all of $\mathbb{R}$? You can show local existence and uniqueness  by solving for $y'$ using the implicit function theorem and using the fact that this map is locally  Lipschitz

Comment: @LutzLehmann I believe the problem wants global uniqueness, although I'll keep in mind that uniqueness holds locally.

Comment: @whpowell96 thanks for the advice, but I believe the problem wants global uniqueness.

Comment: Uniqueness is always local. The opposite is to have two solutions branching out from the same point, which is a local situation. But you could always take the derivative of the equation to get an explicit second-order equation where these questions are simpler to answer (leading to the same answers of course).

Comment: $y(x)=x$ $(x \in \mathbb{R})$ is not a solution, since $\log(x)$ is not defined for $x<0$. Solutions should be defined on $(0, \infty)$. So $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ shlould be replaced by $C^1((0,\infty))$

Comment: @Gerd yes you're right! Edited.